# Undefined local variable but the variable is defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails project, I have following error:

```
undefined local variable or method ` response' for #<Deliveries::CheckJobService:0x00007fce8548dd60> Did you mean? response
```

And here is the code:

```
delivery_status = response['status']
```

I don't see the error

I try new things, and the error is even weirder:

```
    def call
      return false if @order.stuart_job_id.nil?
      response = stuart_check_job
      if response.nil?
        @order.update(delivery_status: 'sth went wrong')
      else
        delivery_status = 2
        delivered_at = 4
        @order.update(delivery_status: delivery_status, delivered_at: delivered_at)
      end

      return true
    end
```

This is the error:

```
undefined local variable or method ` 2' for #<Deliveries::CheckJobService:0x00007fce8490fc40>
```

I don't see any single quotation

Comment: Can you provide more code?

Comment: Look carefully at the error messages, they're complaining about `' response'` and `' 2'` (note the odd leading space). Do you have unexpected Unicode whitespace after the `=` in `delivery_status = response['status']` or `delivery_status = 2`?

Comment: I don't know the reason, I deleted everything and problem was gone, but I couldn't see anything with my eyes. Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm guessing the culprit here was [non-breaking space characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) which are super easy to type by mistake on Macs. They look just like spaces but are not treated as spaces by the parser. You can find the pesky little bastards by displaying invisible characters in your editor.

Comment: thanks a lot, I spent quite time and I was very confused, now happy to know the reason. I know for next time